# Why is ColdFusion Server misinterpreting an uploaded file's MIME type?

Tags: coldfusion, mime-types

I have an application where I allow users to upload supporting documents. I'm using the cffile tag to save the files.

The tag looks like this:

```
<cffile action="upload" 
        destination="path..."
        nameconflict="makeunique"
        ACCEPT="application/msword, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/pdf, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
        filefield="outline">
```

An .xls file was uploaded and an error was generated stating that the uploaded file "application/octet-stream" was not accepted.

The question is why was an .xls spreadsheet file interpreted by the server as having a "application/octet-stream" mime-type?

Comment: For some good information on the security of file uploads in ColdFusion, see Pete Freitag's blog entry on the topic at http://www.petefreitag.com/item/701.cfm

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the client's browser had not been configured to pick the correct mime type for .xls files.  Most likely, the mime type of application/octet-stream was sent in the HTTP headers, in the request.

Comment: As Mark pointed out, `application/octet-stream` is the default Content-Type that a browser will send for a binary file that it otherwise doesn't have a mime-type for.  The user likely doesn't have Excel installed so the browser doesn't know what to tell the server other than `application/octet-stream`.

Answer (score 0):

forget about the `accept` attribute since CF (9 and below) only checks file extension even if the client browser sends the correct MIME type.

Just have the file uploaded, and then check the file extension against your white list.

Without `accept`, you'll not even get that exception.

Answer (score -1):

### I don't think the answer below is correct but I'm leaving it here to help complete the discussion. See my comment below. -mk

Uh oh... I hate to disagree with Sun Flower but the issue here is extension mapping *on the server* not on the client. The file arrives on the server and ColdFusion "looks up" the mime type based on the extension. Having never installed Excel on your server it's quite possible there is no associated mime type on it. Remember that *nothing that depends on the client* is going to help you here. The file arrives, it has an extension and the extension must match something that the *server* knows about.

If this is windows you can add the mime types to IIS (just do a search for "mime types - IIS6 or IIS7 for instructions) and *I believe* that it will automatically add the associated mime type to the underlying registry hive. Otherwise it is a registry hack. I'm going from memory here and I'm too tired to look it up :)

---

Sorry - missed your question about application/octet-stream. That is the default mime type for an arbitrary file. Sort of a catch-all.

Comment: The browser supplies the Content-Type header for each file it is uploading and has nothing to do with the mime-type settings on the server.  This is covered in RFC 1867 which is referenced by several other specifications on the topic and is the reason why security specialists (esp. Pete Freitag for ColdFusion; see http://www.petefreitag.com/item/701.cfm) stress that the reported mime-type cannot be trusted (at least in ColdFuion 9 and earlier).  ColdFusion 10 optionally handles verification somewhat differently.  The browser is the one who sets the Content-Type though.

Comment: Having read Pete's article I will defer to him. I suspect he is right about this. I have always thought (because like Pete I don't trust the "Accept" attribute) that CF is ignoring the mime type in the header and going by the mime type mapping on the server based on the file extension. I'll do some testing